# record:editform for input lookup field pop up search option is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I have created a a lightning component record edit form in VF, which has a input lookup field for custom object named Heading.
In the lightning component when I search for a Heading name, it will display the heading names.

The issue is consider I am searching for a name Accountants, and in the Heading  object we have 10 records with name Accountants (we are differentiating with code).
In my lookup search it will show only 5 Accountants, I am not able to view the other 5 with different codes.
If I do the same in record level,then there is a search pop will appear which shows all lightning.

Whether we can show the same pop up search window in record edit form

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="SampleListing__c" >
        <lightning:messages />        
        <div class="slds-form_horizontal slds-form slds-grid slds-wrap">                
            <lightning:outputField aura:id="firstNameField" class="slds-size_6-of-8 left-align" fieldName = "Name" />
            <lightning:outputField aura:id="DField" class="slds-size_6-of-8 left-align"   fieldName="Dir__c"  />               
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="DSField" class="slds-size_6-of-8" fieldName="Section__c"  />
            <lightning:inputField aura:id="DHField" required="true" class="slds-size_6-of-8" fieldName="Heading__c" />                      
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="update" label="Execute" onclick="{!c.onSubmit}"/>
        </div>        
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this component and the search popup works for me.

[image]

Just click the search box and it will open.

[image]

This is the sample code I have used. Just Contact object fields which includes Account as lookup.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
       onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
        objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}">
       <!--  the messages component is for error messages -->
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" aura:id="LastName"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" aura:id="AccountId"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" aura:id="Birthdate"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="AssistantPhone" aura:id="AssistantPhone"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" aura:id="Email"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="LeadSource" aura:id="LeadSource"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Lead_Source_2__c" aura:id="Lead_Source"/>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

You can find detail code here: https://newstechnologystuff.wordpress.com/2018/10/06/lightningrecordeditform-save-data-without-apex/

Comment: Whether this pop up search is from lightning:recordEditForm field  lightning:inputField search

Comment: @Rose I'm using lightning:inputField `<lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" aura:id="AccountId"/>`

Comment: ,Could you please share the coding as that pop up is not working for me.In the <aura:component controller="Controller" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable" access="global" >

Comment: @Rose check my updated answer.

Comment: yes its working from lightning component.                                            But my lightning component is inside the visualforce page.From the VF page that pop up search not working.Thank you for comment

Comment: @Rose did you ever find solution to this? I have Lightning Comp in VF and cannot seem to figure out the search dialog.